# Gnome-calender Authentication Request

Tags: gnome, 18.04, authentication, calendar

[image: Pop-Up ScreenShot]

In The Above ScreenShot there is some pop-up thats i will get when open some application. please kindly solve my problem how to close its permanently. I am Using 18.04 LTS
**How to trun its close**

> Please Note:- Already Remove Social Account And Also done Reset of Gnome

then Also Its not Solve.

Comment: As u see the pop up in the screenshot this popup i will always get when login or open some add how to turn its close

Comment: not get proper solution